# Treating a forced downcast as optional will never produce 'nil'

Tags: swift, option-type, downcast, forced-unwrapping

I've been playing around with Swift and discovered that when down casting an object to be inserted into a dictionary, I get a weird warning: `Treating a forced downcast to 'String' as optional will never produce 'nil'`. If I replace `as` with `as?` then the warning goes away.

```
func test() -> AnyObject! {
  return "Hi!"
}

var dict = Dictionary<String,String>()
dict["test"]=test() as String
```

Apple's documentation says the following

> Because downcasting can fail, the type cast operator comes in two different forms. The optional form, `as?`, returns an optional value of the type you are trying to downcast to. The forced form, `as`, attempts the downcast and force-unwraps the result as a single compound action.

I'm unclear as to why using `as?` instead of `as` is correct here. Some testing reveals that if I change test() to return an Int instead of a String, the code will quit with an error if I continue using `as`. If I switch to using `as?` then the code will continue execution normally and skip that statement (dict will remain empty). However, I'm not sure why this is preferable. In my opinion, I would rather the program quit with an error and let me know that the cast was unsuccessful then simply ignore the erroneous statement and keep executing.

According to the documentation, I should use the forced form "only when you are sure that the downcast will always succeed." In this case I am sure that the downcast will always succeed since I know `test()` can only return a String so I would assume this is a perfect situation for the forced form of down casting. So why is the compiler giving me a warning?

Comment: First of all, there's a lot of Cocoa type bridging going on, because without `import Foundation`, it wouldn't even compile, because `String` is not a class type and is not compatible with `AnyObject`. If you change the last `String` to `NSString`, the warning goes away, meaning probably that it is an issue with you using `String`, a non-class type, in the `as`.

Comment: @newacct Interestingly enough, if you replace String with NSString in either the Dictionary definition or the downcast, the warning goes away. If you replace String with NSString in **both** places, however, the warning remains.

Comment: **NOTE**: Since Swift 2, many of the functionalities of `as` have been removed, and been replaced with `as!`. So you you will get the same error when you use `as!` (using `as` will not generate this error anymore)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at your last line, and explode it to see what's happening:

```
let temporaryAnyObject = test()
let temporaryString = temporaryAnyObject as String
dict["test"] = temporaryString
```

The error is on the second line, where you are telling the compiler to enforce that `temporaryAnyObject` is definitely a `String`. The code will still compile (assuming you don't treat warnings as errors), but will crash if `temporaryAnyObject` is not actually a `String`.

The way `as` works, with no `?`, is basically saying "from now on, treat the result of this expression as that type IF the result is actually of that type, otherwise we've become inconsistent and can no longer run.

The way `as?` works (with the `?`) is saying "from now on, treat the result of this expression as that type IF the result is actually of that type, otherwise the result of this expression is `nil`.

So in my exploded example above, if `test()` does return a `String`, then the `as` downcast succeeds, and `temporaryString` is now a `String`. If `test()` doesn't return a `String`, but say an `Int` or anything else not subclassed from String, then the `as` fails and the code can no longer continue to run.

This is because, as the developer in complete control, you told the system to behave this way by not putting the optional `?` indicator. The `as` command specifically means that you do not tolerate optional behavior and you require that downcast to work.

If you had put the `?`, then `temporaryString` would be `nil`, and the third line would simple remove the "test" key/value pair from the dictionary.

This might seem strange, but that's only because this is the opposite default behavior of many languages, like Obj-C, which treat everything as optional by default, and rely on you to place your own checks and asserts.

**Edit - Swift 2 Update**

Since Swift 2, the forced, failable downcast operator `as` has been removed, and is replaced with `as!`, which is much Swiftier. The behavior is the same.

Comment: I understand what you're saying about "as" vs "as?" but I still don't get why the warning appears. Furthermore, if I split my code into three lines like you outlined the warning actually disappears. It only shows up when the statement occurs in one line.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Well, that's actually because I wasn't incorrect in the explosion. This is actually what it would be: `let temporaryAnyObject: AnyObject = test(); let temporaryString: String? = temporaryAnyObject as String; dict["test"] = temporaryString` and as you'll see, that gives the same warning.

Comment: And the reason why is because `dict["test"] = *` is expecting a String?, so the change I just posted explicitly types as a String?, not a String!. Think about the "as" as a function. The "as" function returns a String! whereas "as?" returns as String?

Comment: Ah! I see. I was missing the fact that the dictionary was expecting a String? Thanks!

Comment: This stems from the fact that you can remove a key (let's say "apples") by calling dict["apples"] = nil.

Comment: With yesterday's update to the Swift compiler, the warning now offers a solution of putting the downcast in parentheses instead of replacing it with an optional downcast.

Answer (score 6):

<sub>You can solve this warning from two angles. 1. The value you return 2. The type that you are *expected* to return. The other answer speaks about the 1st angle. I'm speaking about the 2nd angle</sub>

This is because you are returning a **forced unwrapped and casted** value for an **optional**. The compiler is like, "*If you really want to just force cast all optionals then why not just make the expected return parameter to be a **non-optional***"

For example if you wrote

```
func returnSomething<T> -> T?{ // I'm an optional, I can handle nils SAFELY and won't crash.

return UIViewController as! T // will never return a safe nil, will just CRASH

}
```

Basically you told yourself (and the compiler) I want to handle `nil`s safely but then in the very next line, you said nah, I don't!!!

The compiler would give a warning:

> Treating a forced downcast to 'T' as optional will never produce 'nil'

An alternative is to remove the `?`

```
func returnSomething<T>() -> T{ // I can't handle nils

    return UIViewController() as! T // I will crash on nils
}
```

---

Having that said, likely the best way is to not use force cast and just do:

```
func returnSomething<T>() -> T?{ // I can handle nils

    return UIViewController() as? T // I won't crash on nils
}
```

Comment: Not force casting worked for me (e.g. `as?`), thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there is bug open about this warning fo some years now...
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-4209 So it shows even in situations where it is obvious what you are doing and right.